# Define mainClass at Maven-Shade Plugin while using Java dynamic web project

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am using maven-shade-plugin at a Java dynamic web project. The following snippet shows the usage:

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In the properties-section of pom.xml i have to define now the mainClass:

```xml
    <properties>
        <mainClass>com.mycompany.ClassName</mainClass>
    </properties>
```

What class name do i have to put inside to be able to get rid of the message "no manifest attribute found." ? i know its a web project, so i do not have a class containing a main-Method. There should be a class at the webcontainer sources with a main-Method. Is there an easy way to find the name of this class?

Thanks a lot.

Alex

Comment: Your main class which has either `public static void main(String[] args)` or extends `javafx.application.Application` class

Comment: I have added some explanations. Its a web project, so there is not explicit main method written by myself. Why do you guess javafx? Its not UI-based.

Comment: web applications not needed to be using shade plugin just use the packaging to war.

Comment: When you say "its a web project" - what do you mean exactly? are you expecting to create a WAR as a result artifact? If so - it doesn't have main class and in general you should probably use packaging=war to prepare the WAR. If its a JAR - its not a WEB project even if it stars some web server internally (like embedded jetty, tomcat etc.) . So further clarifications are needed here...

Comment: Actually in Eclipse its a "Dynamic Web project". At the end a war and a jar file are created. I would prefer the jar-file, because i just want to have one single file, which is ready to be executed without any further installed webservers. Is it guaranteed, that alle dependecies are packed within a war-file?